# How to create a vertical line?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to place a vertical line on my Window like the following:

[image]

I have tried to create a `"STATIC"` control with the `SS_SUNKEN` style and with a width of `2`:

```
CreateWindowEx(NULL, "STATIC", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_SUNKEN, 10, 10, 2, 200, hParentWindow, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

It had worked, but I am wondering if this is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: One way. You may also paint with code, in this case you may also want to handle themes properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [DrawEdge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function if you wanted to do the drawing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a Static control is to render the sunken border yourself.

If no theme is applied, use [DrawEdge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162477.aspx).

If a theme is applied to the window, call [DrawThemeBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) passing `GP_LINEVERT` for *iPartId*. See [Parts and States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210.aspx) for additional information on theme rendering.